# Java Type mismatch - cannot convert from int[][] error in constructor

Tags: java

my constructor is

```
public class Figure{
    int[][] x;
    Color y;
    public Figure(int[][] x , Color y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
```

and i am initializing object in the following way:

```
Figure s = new Figure({{0,1,1},{1,1,0}},Color.ORANGE);
```

getting the following error:

Type mismatch - cannot convert from int[][] to Figure
Syntax error on tokens: misplaced construct
                         Variable declarator expected instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to create the matrix like this:

```
new Figure(new int[][]{{0,1,1}, {1,1,0}},Color.ORANGE);
```

Or a less dirty way: spread the matrix construction over a couple of lines:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[2][];
matrix[0] = new int[]{0,1,1};
matrix[1] = new int[]{1,1,0};

new Figure(matrix, Color.ORANGE);
```

Comment: This should work : `new Figure(new int[][]{{0,1,1}, {1,1,0}},Color.ORANGE);`

Comment: Thanks it works:)
Should i call new Object[] evry time i am using array or list as parameter?

Comment: @user1551603: Glad to help! Now, to mark your question as solved, you can accept my answer by clicking the tick under the score of my answer.